# TextWatcher keep looping after enter the keys

Tags: java, android

https://gist.github.com/tigers2020/e10b6981acfbceb06a673db00f3d8f5f

so, I try to make editTextView convert String to a pattern like this

```
700 -> 7:00
570 -> 6:10
43 -> 0:43
```

it works well but the problem is it keep looping one after another added.
what I mean, when I insert number it runs 1 time and inserts another number it runs 2 times 4 times 8 times... and eventually crashed.

do you guys have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up a proxy pass. In your apache virtual host file,make these changes

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName mydomain

ProxyRequests off

<Proxy *>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyPass / http://localhost:4004/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:4004/
ProxyPreserveHost on
</VirtualHost>
```